# How to enable logging in my deployed SSIS package?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, logging, ssis

I have created and deployed an SSIS package to the SQL server (2005). I did not enable any logging in my deployed package. I have configured a job to run the package. I cannot modify the package now.

Is there anything I can do to have **some kind of logging** for the package or something in the SQL Agent job to provide some logging?

The **SQL Agent job history** is not being retained, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about changing your Job Step type from Integration Services to an OS command. From there, you'll invoke [dtexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) from the command line and redirect the output to a file. Logic approximately

```
dtexec.exe /sql "\OptionalFolder\PackageName" /Server MyServer /reporting V > PackageName.log
```

You might also be interested in the ConsoleLog argument for dtexec. Do note that this will overwrite the file each time the package is run. If you want multiple runs in a file, then use `>>` instead of the single redirection.

### Edit

Your current job is probably defined something like this. Right click on the job and script the job as a create to a new query editor window. Find the sections where `@subsystem=N'SSIS'`

```
USE [msdb]
GO

DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'MyJob', 
        @enabled=0, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT

-- This is approximates your existing job step of type (assuming defaults)
-- SQL Server Integration Services Package
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Run SSIS Package', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        @command=N'/SQL "\OptionalFolder\PackageName" /SERVER MyServer /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
```

All that is really doing is making a call to the correct dtexec (32 or 64 bit) executable for your version of SQL Server (in case you have side by side installs). You *might* be able to just edit the command line manually and redirect output. I've never tried that but in theory it should work.

[image]

If it doesn't, then what I know *will* work is to explicitly call the executable from a job step. The above step would be replaced with something like

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Run SSIS from OS type', 
    @step_id=1, 
    @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
    @on_success_action=3, 
    @on_fail_action=2, 
    @retry_attempts=0, 
    @retry_interval=0, 
    @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'CmdExec', 
    @command=N'"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /sql "\OptionalFolder\PackageName" /Server MyServer /reporting V > PackageName.log', 
    @database_name=N'master', 
    @flags=0
```

### Edit 2

Unbeknownst to me, the redirect `>` seems to be throwing an error in the OS sub step. Which could make sense given that a job step needs to be able to capture the output streams as well. At any rate, the approach is still the same, redirect the output to a file---we'll simply update the mechanism.

## Batch approach

Create a .bat file or a pair of them. I called mine `RunPackage.bat` and `RunPackage32.bat` and put them into a folder called C:\ssis. The contents of them are

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /sql "\%1" /Server MyServer /reporting V > C:\ssis\%1.log
```

and

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /sql "\%1" /Server MyServer /reporting V > C:\ssis\%1.log
```

The job step remains a type of Operating System but the actual command becomes

```
@command=N'C:\ssis\RunPackage.bat Package'
```

The SQL Agent, or the proxy for OS steps, will need read and write access to wherever you log the details.

Comment: This could be an option but not for me as I am tied up. Cannot redeploy and cannot change the execution method. Just have rights on that SQL job. But, I'll mark this as answer if I can't find anything else by tomorrow.

Comment: @billinkc is not asking you to redeploy, just change the sql job that is executing the package.  This is the only way to do this under the almost unreasonable restrictions you state in your question.

Comment: Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 9.00.5000.00 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Option ">" is not valid.  The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.

Comment: I have added a second update. I was able to recreate your issue and have resolved it. Apologies on that.